# How to use NSURLSessionDataTask in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone help me? I can't find a good example for the completion syntax.

```
var url : NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchTerm)&media=software")
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession.sessionWithConfiguration(config)

NSURLSessionDataTask(session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: ((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)?)
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's **unclear what you're asking**, but I noticed that you have a couple of errors in the code:

1. You should create your `session` using `NSURLSession(configuration: config)`
2. `session.dataTaskWithRequest` returns a `NSURLSessionDataTask`, so there's no need to wrap it inside `NSURLSessionDataTask()` (a.k.a instantiating a new `NSURLSessionDataTask` object).
3. The completion handler is a closure and here's how you create that particular clousure:

   ```
   {(data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) in

       // your code

   }
   ```

Here's the updated code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchTerm)&media=software")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

    // notice that I can omit the types of data, response and error

    // your code

});

// do whatever you need with the task e.g. run
task.resume()
```

Comment: You can accept my answer if it was what you were looking for. :)

Comment: is it possible to use this implementation for POST as well?

Comment: how do you println the error message?

Comment: make sure to call task .resume() after the closure. this will fire off the request

Comment: I tried this code but I get an syntax error : "'URLWithString' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSURL(string:)'" at the first line starting with "var url" . I am using SDK 8.1. Any hints ?

Comment: @user1344545 You should do what the error says. ;)

Comment: Ok. Understood. Still learning swift :-)

Comment: Latest swift wants me to use `NSURLRequest(URL: url!)`. Other than that, it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: See my update for Swift 3.0 below.

Answer (score 13):

If you have problems with completion syntax, you can create function for completion before calling dataTaskWithRequest(..) to make it clearer

```
func handler (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) {
            //handle what you need
        }

session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: handler)
```

Comment: In your simple example right here you have made the structure of closures clear to me. The fact that you can replace them with a func is very enlightening.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use it simply by :-

```
let url = "api url"

let nsURL = NSURL

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
(data, response, error) in
   // your condition on success and failure
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated @duemonk's code for Swift 3:

```
do {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.example.com/api/v1")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

         if error != nil {

              print(error!.localizedDescription)

         }

         else {
              print(response)
         }
     })

    task.resume()
}

catch {
// handle the error
}
```

Comment: you haven't added anything about the request, if it is SET or GET

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://url.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
    });

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in 
    //code
)}
```

Hopefully Xcode will be updated to support auto-complete for these, cause the syntax is kind of tricky, and Swift doesn't appear to support declaring the return type yet when used like this.

Comment: Yea, I've noticed that the auto-complete when using swift is pretty hit and miss. There have been a couple of instances that it stopped working all together and I had to restart Xcode.

Comment: I noticed that even in the Xcode 6.1 GM the auto-complete of params inside the closure doesn't work. And you cant "Jump to definition" while the syntax is incorrect, making the feature rather useless.