# NSURLSession error with PHP connection

Tags: swift2, nsurlsession

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
```

In this code I'm getting an error for `dataTaskWithRequest(request)` for with my PHP connection. It worked before migrating to Swift 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct syntax:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

    // your code

})
```

Sample code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040893/how-to-use-nsurlsessiondatatask-in-swift) answer:

```
var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchTerm)&media=software")
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

    // notice that I can omit the types of data, response and error

    // your code

});

// do whatever you need with the task
```

**UPDATE:**

```
let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=&media=software")!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        do {
            let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
                print("Not a Dictionary")
                //get your JSONData here from dictionary.

                return
            }
            print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")
        }
        catch let JSONError as NSError {
            print("\(JSONError)")
        }

    })
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to fix that ? because I dont get it

Comment: if i put in this "if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject?, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) {"

Comment: it gives me ""use of unresolved identifyer dataObject" before the new xcode it worked like that

Comment: Happy to help you..:)