# Downloading JSON with NSURLSession doesn't return any data

Tags: json, swift, connection

I am currently trying to download, parse and print JSON from an URL.
So far I got to this point:

1) A class (JSONImport.swift), which handles my import:

```
    var data = NSMutableData();
        let url = NSURL(string:"http://headers.jsontest.com");
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
        var jsonError:NSError?;
        var response : NSURLResponse?;

        func startConnection(){

            let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:apiHandler)
            task.resume();

            self.apiHandler(data,response: response,error: jsonError);

        }

        func apiHandler(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?)
        {
            do{
                let jsonData : NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary;
                print(jsonData);
            }
            catch{
                print("API error: \(error)");
            }
        }
```

My **problem** is, that the data in

```
do{
            let jsonData : NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary;
            print(jsonData);
        }
```

remains empty.
When I debug,the connection starts successfully, with the given url as a parameter. But my jsonData variable doesn't get printed. Instead the catch block throws the error, stating that there is no data in my variable:

```
API error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."
```

Can someone please help me with this?
What am I missing?

Thank you all very much in advance!

[Edited after switching from NSURL Connection to NSURLSession]

Comment: Just a suggestion: stop using NSURLConnection anyway, it is deprecated, use NSURLSession instead.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Haven't been aware of that.

Comment: Any advise on how to use it in my code snipped?

Comment: Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24041204/2227743 but there's plenty of others on SO. Search for `[swift] NSURLSession`.

Comment: Edited the question :)

Comment: Don't forget to also change the title... ;)

Comment: Good call, where would I be without you :D

Comment: Ahah. :) I've made an answer, a simple example, it should help you understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to use NSURLSession with a very convenient "completion handler".

This function contains the network call and has the "completion handler" (a callback for when the data will be available):

```
func getDataFrom(urlString: String, completion: (data: NSData)->()) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
            // print(response)
            if let data = data {
                completion(data: data)
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } else {
        // URL is invalid
    }
}
```

You can use it like this, inside a new function, with a "trailing closure":

```
func apiManager() {
    getDataFrom("http://headers.jsontest.com") { (data) in
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
            if let jsonDict = json as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonDict)
            } else {
                // JSON data wasn't a dictionary
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("API error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that one out and compare it to what I've done wrong :)

Comment: Took me a little bit longer than you to figure that out :D Thank you a lot sir! :)