# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on return

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

I am calling Url which will give me Json in get() function.
I am calling get() function from another class and try to return result of Json in Array format. but it shows Found null error on return statement . when I tried to print values of Json it writing correctly.
This is my code in swift.

```
 func get() -> NSArray
        {
            let postEndpoint: String =  "Link_For_JSON_Data"
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
            var jsonArray : NSArray?
            var jsonArray1 : NSArray?

            session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                // Make sure we get an OK response
                guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
                    realResponse.statusCode == 200 else
                {
                        print("Not a 200 response")
                        return
                }

                // Read the JSON
                do
                {
                    if let contentString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    {
                        // Print what we got from the call
                        jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
                        print("jsonArray here", jsonArray)
                        // Update the label

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                            { () -> Void in
                            self.getDataFormREST(jsonArray!)
                            }

                    }
                }

                catch
                {
                    print("bad things happened")
                }

            }).resume()

       return jsonArray!
        }

     func getDataFormREST(resultArray: NSArray) //-> NSArray
        {
            //        let resultDictionary = resultArray[(searchDetails)!-1] as! NSDictionary
            testArray = resultArray
            print("TESTArray ON ",testArray)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading JSON with NSURLSession doesn't return any data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289389/downloading-json-with-nsurlsession-doesnt-return-any-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a function that does an async call and then returns the results as the function result. That's not how async code works. Your function queues up the async `dataTaskWithURL` request, and then returns before it has even had a chance to send the request, much less receive the results.

You have to rewrite your `get()` function to be a void function (no result returned) but take a completion block. Then, in your data task's completion handler you get the data from the `jsonArray` and call the `get()` function's completion block, passing it the `jsonArray`.

See this project I posted on Github that illustrates what I'm talking about:

[**SwiftCompletionHandlers on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/SwiftCompletionHandlers)

Comment: I am little confuse. can you show how can I use this is my code @Duncan C