# Downloading JSON data fails at NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to get a JSON file from a URL and return the contents using Swift. However, the code fails at the line `let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse`  in the following code. I get an exception at this line and Xcode goes into debug mode.

```
class func downloadJSONFile()->AnyObject
    {
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var json:AnyObject = ""
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {

                do{
                    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                }

            }

        }

        task.resume()

        return json
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't *return* from an asynchronous call. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35358750/2227743 Also, you should not *force cast* the response, it may not be here, so check the error parameter first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. If there is any error in the request, `response` will be `nil`, and thus your attempt to force cast it will result in fatal error. Do not use forced unwrapping/casting when dealing with network responses.
2. There is a deeper problem here that you're trying to return data from a method that runs asynchronously. You should change your method to not return anything, per se, but rather supply a completion handler by which you can asynchronously pass back the relevant data:

   ```
    class func downloadJSONFile(completionHandler: @escaping (Any?) -> Void) {
        let requestURL = URL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            // check for fundamental networking errors

            guard
                error == nil,
                let data = data
            else {
                print(error ?? "Other error")
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }

            guard
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200 ..< 300) ~= httpResponse.statusCode
            else {
                print("Invalid status code")
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                completionHandler(json)
            } catch let parseError {
                print("Error parsing: \(parseError)")
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
   ```

   and then you call it, using the completion handler (or use trailing closure syntax, like shown below):

   ```
    APIClass.downloadJSONFile() { json in
        guard json != nil else {
            print("there was some problem")
            return
        }

        // now you can use `json` here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // and if you're doing any model or UI updates, dispatch that back to the main queue
        }
    }

    // but do not use `json` here, as the above runs asynchronously
   ```
3. Note, if you wanted to supply the error information back to the calling routine, you could change it to also return the error information, e.g.:

   ```
   enum DownloadError: Error {
       case networkError(Error)
       case notHTTPResponse
       case invalidHTTPResponse(Int)
       case parseError(Error)
   }

   class func downloadJSONFile(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Any, Error>) -> Void) {
       let requestURL = URL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
       let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
       let session = URLSession.shared
       let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
           if let error = error {
               completionHandler(.failure(DownloadError.networkError(error)))
               return
           }

           guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let data = data else {
               completionHandler(.failure(DownloadError.notHTTPResponse))
               return
           }

           guard 200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
               completionHandler(.failure(DownloadError.invalidHTTPResponse(httpResponse.statusCode)))
               return
           }

           do {
               let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
               completionHandler(.success(json))
           } catch let parseError {
               completionHandler(.failure(DownloadError.parseError(parseError)))
           }
       }

       task.resume()
   }
   ```

   And, obviously, the call would change to take both parameters:

   ```
   APIClass.downloadJSONFile() { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)

       case .success(let value):
           // and then it would be like before ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. When using `URLSession` in iOS 9 and later, it will not permit cleartext requests (i.e. "http" is not permitted, only "https" is, by default). You can force the app to permit non-https requests by adding the following to your `info.plist`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254874/1271826 for more information

   ```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>learnswiftonline.com</key>
            <dict>
                <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
   ```

Comment: FWIW, I've updated the above to use contemporary Swift syntax, but I wouldn't generally use `JSONSerialization` and `Any` as types. We'd generally use `JSONDecoder` nowadays, but it seems like it's beyond the scope of this question...