# Empty array after completion handler?

Tags: arrays, swift, completionhandler, completion

I've created a method which returns an `array`, but the `array` gets constructed inside of a completion handler of `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL)` method. I inserted a url and the data task gets executed fine. I used the debug logger to check up on the `array` and it gets constructed perfectly (appending multiple objects to the array using a `for-in loop`). Only problem is after the completion handler (so after I called `task.resume()` method), the same array that got constructed inside the completion handler is suddenly empty and contains 0 elements. How can I get objects created inside of a completion handler to use them afterwards (for example if I want to return the object to the caller of the method in which the dataTask was started)?

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: You are running an asynchronous method and thus it can't wait for it to finish before returning the array otherwise it would be a synchronous method.

Comment: What you need is to pass the resulto using the completion handler, to post a notification or use a delegate

Comment: After calling resume just means the session started

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35358750/2303865