# Cannot invoke 'URLSession' with an argument list of type '(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)'

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, invoke

Notice that i've tried so many solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040893/how-to-use-nsurlsessiondatatask-in-swift) and none worked.

here is [screenshot](http://i.hizliresim.com/jX5Qg9.png) and code;

```
func downloadItems() {

    let urlE: String = "http://alicelik.me/forios/service.php"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlE) else {
        print("Error: cannot")
        return
    }

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    var session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL){
        (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error)
        }
        return()
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Here is URLSession func;

```
@nonobjc func URLSession(session: URLSessionConfiguration, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.data.append(data as Data);

}

@nonobjc func URLSession(session: URLSessionConfiguration, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}
```

note: *URLSession and *URLSessionConfiguration in func URLSession(session *) giving same error.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on my Xcode!

Comment: try with new func codes. it will show you error now. i forgot first.

Comment: Shouldn't it be guard **let** error?

Comment: Try removing your two _URLSession func_ , those do not work as you are not setting the delegate of the `URLSession`, also you are putting `@nonobjc` to the two funcs, which makes the funcs completely useless.

Comment: thanks guys, first nonobjc is useless thanks @OOPer and sec when i remove 2 URLSession func it worked fine. i realized after Solih thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing URLSession func will fix issue.

```
func downloadItems() {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var session = URLSession()
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)
    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.data.append(data as Data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    } else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, solved it by:

`var session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration)`

Comment: Change ['NSURLSession' with 'URLSession'] and ['URLSession' with  'urlSession'] works great.

Comment: Why do I need to specify Foundation for this to work?  It did, but I have no idea why.